# How to target multiple data attribute at once

Tags: javascript, arrays, attributes

I have a list of products where i want to target them using the attribute "data-ga-product" which is unique for each product. What i want to achieve is to insert a span with a message like "New In" to these products I'm targeting.

I've got this working if I do this separately but can you target several products at once so there's no need for duplication of code? I've tried the below but it only targets the first selector, or is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to achieve?

```js
// Attempt at targeting multiple data attributes at once
var targetProduct = document.querySelectorAll('[data-ga-product="04245"]','[data-ga-product="263743"]' ).forEach(function (el){
    el.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<span>New In</span>");
});


/*
Targeting each indivudally
var targetProduct = document.querySelector('[data-ga-product="04245"]');
targetProduct.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<span>New In</span>");
var targetProduct = document.querySelector('[data-ga-product="263743"]');
targetProduct.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<span>New In</span>");
*/
```

```css
.container {padding: 5px 0;}
```

```html
<article class="container" data-ga-product="04245">
  <div class="productContent">
    <a class="productTitle" href="#product1">Product 1</a>
    <div class="productPrice">€&nbsp;19,90</div>
  </div>
</article>

<article class="container" data-ga-product="05395">
  <div class="productContent">
    <a class="productTitle" href="#product2">Product 2</a>
    <div class="productPrice">€&nbsp;109,90</div>
  </div>
</article>

<article class="container" data-ga-product="263743">
  <div class="productContent">
    <a class="productTitle" href="#product3">Product 3</a>
    <div class="productPrice">€&nbsp;59,90</div>
  </div>
</article>

<article class="container" data-ga-product="60493">
  <div class="productContent">
    <a class="productTitle" href="#product4">Product 4</a>
    <div class="productPrice">€&nbsp;23,90</div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think there is a way to look for a value in a array variable when working with `querySelector()`.

You can conditionally insert your element inside your `forEach()` though, if you want concise code.

```js
// Attempt at creating this as an array
var targetProduct = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-ga-product]')].forEach(function (el){
if(['04245' , '263743'].indexOf(el.getAttribute('data-ga-product')) > -1)    
el.querySelector('.productTitle').insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<span>New In</span>");
});
```

```css
.container {padding: 5px 0;}
```

```html
<article class="container" data-ga-product="04245">
  <div class="productContent">
    <a class="productTitle" href="#product1">Product 1</a>
    <div class="productPrice">€&nbsp;19,90</div>
  </div>
</article>

<article class="container" data-ga-product="05395">
  <div class="productContent">
    <a class="productTitle" href="#product2">Product 2</a>
    <div class="productPrice">€&nbsp;109,90</div>
  </div>
</article>

<article class="container" data-ga-product="263743">
  <div class="productContent">
    <a class="productTitle" href="#product3">Product 3</a>
    <div class="productPrice">€&nbsp;59,90</div>
  </div>
</article>

<article class="container" data-ga-product="60493">
  <div class="productContent">
    <a class="productTitle" href="#product4">Product 4</a>
    <div class="productPrice">€&nbsp;23,90</div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Note : I use `...` to convert the `NodeList` (returned by `querySelectorAll()`) to an array. `forEach()` method is also implemented on the `NodeList`, but quoting the docs :

> However, some older browsers have not implemented NodeList.forEach()

Comment: Thanks for this, one question if i wanted to add the span after the product title how i would i do this?

Comment: I have updated the answer with one more querySelector to make it more specific. There are other ways also to do it, but this matches more with your initial answer.

Comment: Ah didn't realise it was as easy as that, tried a few other things and it wouldn't work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) is also a NodeList protytpe method so no need to spread it into an array. Also it would be more elegant to do like `document.querySelectorAll('[data-ga-product]').forEach(el => ['04245','263743'].includes(el.dataset.gaProduct) && el.querySelector('.productTitle').insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<span>New In</span>"));`.